# What is the Main object when running a Scala script?

Tags: scala, program-entry-point

For example the following code:

```scala
object Test extends App {
  val x = 100
  println(Main.x+"  "+x)
}
```

Seems invalid since it won't compile given there is no `Main` object define anywhere.
And effectively it doesn't compile in [**Scastie**](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/1yCpvSTARNaJWAKOkpjOnQ/1) nor using a standard `scalac` compiler *(version `2.13.4`)*, nor if you run this code directly on the REPL.

However, if you save it to a file and then you run it using the `scala` command *(same version as before)*; like a script, it runs without problems and produces the following output:

> 100  100

What is that `Main` object? When and why it was added?

Comment: Am a newcomer to scala, I don't understand how Main object is accessing the local fields in the object. The code compiles as we extend App

Comment: Hi there, you are right but when i run on local machine using visual studio code its working perfectly.

Comment: I used scala name.scala rather sclac name.scala and it runs smoothly

Comment: Uhm, you are right. I have no idea what the REPL is doing, why it is there and what is supposed to be its use. I have been using **Scala** for more than 5 years and just today I discovered that. Probably someone like Seth or Martijn would know what is going on, I will ask them in the gitter room just because. But, since the code can't compile on its own I would recommend you to just change it.

Comment: What do you mean by "the Scala command"? What command are you runnning?

Comment: @TomerShetah `scala Test.scala` the same command you use to open the REPL or _(like in this case)_ to run a Scala script.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a REPL?

Comment: @TomerShetah no, in the REPL itself it doesn't work. But it does if you run it like a script, which is what is surprising to me since that effectively feels like invalid code.

Comment: That is surprising indeed. I can't reproduce it though, so it is interesting to understand what are the differences between our environments.

Comment: @TomerShetah that is interesting indeed, what is your scala version and how did you installed? Also, what is your operating system?

Comment: I am running on Mac Scala. 2.13.4

Answer (score 2):

From what I see [`scriptBody()`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/decbd53f1bde4600c8ff860f30a79f028a8e431d/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/parser/Parsers.scala#L389) is responsible for this behavior:

```
    /** This is the parse entry point for code which is not self-contained, e.g.
     *  a script which is a series of template statements.  They will be
     *  swaddled in Trees until the AST is equivalent to the one returned
     *  by compilationUnit().
     */
    def scriptBody(): Tree = {

      // remain backwards-compatible if -Xscript was set but not reasonably
      settings.script.value match {
        case null | "" => settings.script.value = "Main"
        case _ =>
      }
 
      ...

      // pick up object specified by `-Xscript Main`
      def mainModule: Tree = settings.script.valueSetByUser.map(name => searchForMain(TermName(name))).getOrElse(EmptyTree)

      /*  Here we are building an AST representing the following source fiction,
       *  where `moduleName` is from -Xscript (defaults to "Main") and <stmts> are
       *  the result of parsing the script file.
       *
       *  {{{
       *  object moduleName {
       *    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
       *      new AnyRef {
       *        stmts
       *      }
       *  }
       *  }}}
       */
      def repackaged: Tree = {
      ...
```

Basically your script body is forcefully rewritten into something that is

```
object Main {
  // must contain main
}
```

We can confirm that `-Xscript` appearing in these methods indeed controls this behavior:

```
// test.scala
object Test extends App {
  val x = 100
  println(Main.x+"  "+x)
  println(Main.getClass)
  new Exception().printStackTrace()
}
```

With defaults we see that `"Main"` is used and that code is rewritten to have `Main` as starting point (code reused existing `object Test extends App` to create it):

```
> scala test.scala
warning: 1 deprecation (since 2.13.0); re-run with -deprecation for details
100  100
class Main$
java.lang.Exception
    at Main$.delayedEndpoint$Main$1(test.scala:5)
    at Main$delayedInit$body.apply(test.scala:1)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:563)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:561)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:919)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
    at Main$.main(test.scala:1)
    at Main.main(test.scala)
    ...
```

If we specify `Test` as our main, `Main` is not generated and compilation fails

```
> scala -Xscript Test test.scala
test.scala:3: error: not found: value Main
  println(Main.x+"  "+x)
          ^
test.scala:4: error: not found: value Main
  println(Main.getClass)
```

Behavior of e.g. Scastie is different as Scastie defines its own `main` and put your code into it, so this synthetic `Main` is never created (though `Test` was still tampered with).